# Why Guard statement does not work properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create a form which will check if all the fields are filled up. If not, it will notify user to fill up the fields. If all the data is available, it will create new user. My code is like this

```
@IBAction func signUpPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.errorLabel.alpha = 0
    guard let firstNameString = firstName.text, firstNameString.isEmpty,
          let lastNameString = lastName.text, lastNameString.isEmpty,
          let phoneNumberString = phoneNumber.text, phoneNumberString.isEmpty,
          let emailString = email.text, emailString.isEmpty,
          let passwordString = password.text, passwordString.isEmpty
    else {
        self.errorLabel.text = "Please fill up all the fields"
        self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
        return
    }
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailString, password: passwordString) { (auth, err) in
            if (err != nil) {
                self.errorLabel.text = err?.localizedDescription
                self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
            }
```

The problem here is that if all the fields are empty, the error message comes from 'err?.localizedDescription' which is "Incorrect password length". This error is because of inbult validation of Firebase. But if any of the field is not empty, the error shows "Please fill up all the fields"

Comment: Your `isEmpty` conditions look like the should all be opposites -- like `!firstNameString.isEmpty`. Right now, your `guard` returns only if they *are not* empty.

Comment: You need to guard that your values *arent't* empty.

Answer (score 0):

The happy path is if the text fields are **not** empty

```
guard let firstNameString = firstName.text, !firstNameString.isEmpty,
      let lastNameString = lastName.text, !lastNameString.isEmpty,
      let phoneNumberString = phoneNumber.text, !phoneNumberString.isEmpty,
      let emailString = email.text, !emailString.isEmpty,
      let passwordString = password.text, !passwordString.isEmpty else { ...
```